# Lab project template - Greek Language

Tags: languages

I want to use the template from [overleaf](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/university-school-laboratory-report)

but also I want it in Greek.However, I use the babel package but when I compile the .tex it shows strange symbols without meaning. My question is if there is a way to use the above-linked template in Greek.

Comment: You have not given many clues. It helps if you show people the code causing the problem, but I would guess that you have saved the file with the wrong encoding. Make sure your editor saves the file as UTF-8 (unicode), and make sure your file has `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to declare to LaTeX that it is UTF-8.

Comment: You are right !!! I used the \usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc} when I wrote: ellhnika  it shows ελληνικα but when I wrote ελληνικα it translated Ξ•Ξ»Ξ»Ξ•Ξ•Ξ΄ΗΞ΄ΙΞ•